# General Assembly Dash, Task 3, gradients

Tags: css, gradient

I'm currently on the General Assembly Dash site, trying to 'change the paragraph's solid background colour to a semi-transparent linear gradient.  It should begin as solid black at the bottom and end as 40% black at the top.'

```
p {
background: linear-gradient (bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.4));
}
```

It won't accept my answer above and I'm not sure why - any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant this:

```
p { linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.4)); }
```

notice the `0deg`, meaning the gradient will have a vertical angle, going from bottom (`rgba(0,0,0,1)`) and up (`rgba(0,0,0,.4)`).
You can read more about the linear-gradient here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

**[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7vqe0q8j/1/)**

Answer (score -1):

here is a very good tool for all the gradient related things : http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

You can adjust the opacity like you do in photoshop or graphics softwares.

HaveFun!

Comment: Thanks for the handy tool - very interesting.